# Laravel 8 | Auth user profile avatar update

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Hello i can't update user avatar column don't know what i'm doing wrong (
can someone please help me :heart:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: add some images of html and controller

Comment: Can you please add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `<form...` and see if that helps you?

Comment: now i get this error ' Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() '

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update it because your form cannot send the uploaded data to the controller.
You can add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at your form tag to allow the form to process your uploaded data.